# View Rendered Wrong (Vue)

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuetify.js

When you go to a route, the view is rendered "wrong":

I'm using Vuetify, the first time route access rendering is done right.

[image]

when I click edit (EDITAR) I go to another route, where I can make changes to the item record, and when I click save, I go back to the previous route with the following code:

```
axios.patch(`${url}produtos/${this.$route.params.id}`, formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      accept: 'application/json',
    },
  }).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    Toast.open({
      message: 'As Alterações Foram Salvas!',
      type: 'is-success',
      position: 'is-top',
      indefinite: true,
    });
    this.$router.push({ path: `/produtos/${this.$route.params.id}` });
  });
```

However, it does not render as I expected, as it shrinks the iframe inside the Vuetify Carousel and still returns to the previous page at the same position as it was on the item's edit page (At the bottom of the page).

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this happens and how to solve it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem, I was using the Buefy Toast component, and somehow it hindered Iframe loading, it was just removing the buefy to work as it should, now I will find an alternative to Buefy's Toast.

Comment: Check this out, it's quote nice in my opinion:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/snackbars